# Link between forward and inverse regression ($\text{E}(X|Y)$ and $\text{E}(Y|X)$ ;$ \text{var}[\text{E}(X|Y)]$ and $\text{var}[\text{E}(Y|X)]$)

Tags: regression, multivariate-analysis, dimensionality-reduction

In a multivariate context, that is with at least X or Y being a random vector, are there formulae or theorems that link (even remotely) the forward and inverse regression, $\text{E}(X|Y)$ and $\text{E}(Y|X)$ ?
Or alternatively $\text{E}(X_i|Y)$ and $\text{E}(Y|X_i)$, where $X_i$ is a given component of $X$.

Similarly, can something be said about $\text{var}[\text{E}(X|Y)]$ and $\text{var}[\text{E}(Y|X)]$ ?
Or alternatively $\text{var}[\text{E}(X_i|Y)]$  and $\text{var}[\text{E}(Y|X_i)]$, where $X_i$ is a given component of $X$.

Both $X$ and $Y$ are supposed to be random. The typical application
case is that $X$ follows a chosen distribution (for instance a
multigaussian) and $Y$ is a function of $X$.
The link function is too complicated to be used or even unknown (it
is typically a numerical model).
The distribution of $X$, however, is controlled. Thus, one should formulate hypothesis on $X$ if needed.

*Note : this question is related to dimension reduction trhough the sliced inverse regression technique.

It is also related to sensitivity analysis, as
$\text{var}[\text{E}(Y|X)]$ is the numerator of Sobol' index
(surprisingly, the tag `sensitivity-analysis` does not exist -- if
someone with sufficient reputation read this, he might want to create it).*

Comment: Unless both $X$ and $Y$ are random, either $E(X|Y)$ or $E(Y|X)$ is essentially meaningless, so I take it that both are supposed to be random... Have you studied errors-in-variables models? They are used for studying $E(Y|X)$ regression and, by symmetry when both the response and the explanatory variables are random, thus also $E(X|Y)$.

Comment: I added some precisions regarding your first remark. I will have a look at what you suggested.

Comment: Yves is right and has answered your question.  There is no relationship between E(Y|X) and E(X|Y) without specifying the joint distribution.

Comment: @Yves, could you fomulate your comment into an answer ?
What about the variance of conditional expectations ?
What minimal assumptions on the joint distributions would allow to state some resulsts ?

Comment: @Alfred.M  Thank you. Yet I have no more to write... except a few details about the example?

Comment: That would be nice, but I meant to make your text an answer instead of a comment so that I can accept it. It seems that this question might not get any other answer.

Comment: If Yves has given you the best answer which i think he has I don't understand why you put a bounty on the question.  Unless you modify the question there is nothing else to say.  But I agree that he should move hsi comment to the answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $\mathbb{E}(X \vert Y)$ heavily depends on this joint distribution, which is *not* determinated by $\mathbb{E}(Y \vert X)$.
Consider the simple case where $X$ and $Y$ are scalar r.vs and
$Y=X+\varepsilon$ where $\varepsilon$ has mean zero and is independent
of $X$. Depending on the distribution of $\varepsilon$, one can find
examples where the function $\mathbb{E}(X \vert Y=y)$ is respectively
*increasing*, *constant* or *decreasing* in $y$
for large $y$. Yet in all cases, $\mathbb{E}(Y \vert X=x) \equiv x$.